# CodeIgniter: Compilation failed: unrecognized character after (?< at offset 5

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post, preg-replace-callback

I've been creating a website with `CodeIgniter-2.2.6` and successfully created a working website in my local machine.

**Problem 1**

But when I uploaded it to `000webhost` for free hosting, I get this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: preg_replace_callback() [function.preg-replace-callback]:
>   Compilation failed: unrecognized character after (?< at offset 5
>
> Filename: core/Security.php
>
> Line Number: 432

*Code of `core/Security.php` (line 404 to 435):*

```
    /*
     * Sanitize naughty HTML elements
     *
     * If a tag containing any of the words in the list
     * below is found, the tag gets converted to entities.
     *
     * So this: <blink>
     * Becomes: &lt;blink&gt;
     */
    $pattern = '#'
        .'<((?<slash>/*\s*)(?<tagName>[a-z0-9]+)(?=[^a-z0-9]|$)' // tag start and name, followed by a non-tag character
        .'[^\s\042\047a-z0-9>/=]*' // a valid attribute character immediately after the tag would count as a separator
        // optional attributes
        .'(?<attributes>(?:[\s\042\047/=]*' // non-attribute characters, excluding > (tag close) for obvious reasons
        .'[^\s\042\047>/=]+' // attribute characters
        // optional attribute-value
            .'(?:\s*=' // attribute-value separator
                .'(?:[^\s\042\047=><`]+|\s*\042[^\042]*\042|\s*\047[^\047]*\047|\s*(?U:[^\s\042\047=><`]*))' // single, double or non-quoted value
            .')?' // end optional attribute-value group
        .')*)' // end optional attributes group
        .'[^>]*)(?<closeTag>\>)?#isS';

    // Note: It would be nice to optimize this for speed, BUT
    //       only matching the naughty elements here results in
    //       false positives and in turn - vulnerabilities!
    do
    {
        $old_str = $str;
        $str = preg_replace_callback($pattern, array($this, '_sanitize_naughty_html'), $str); // This is line no 432
    }
    while ($old_str !== $str);
    unset($old_str);
```

And This is only given in the script where I post my `form`.

**Problem 2**

And Next problem is I get empty fields when posting a `form`. This is what I get with

```
print_r($_POST);
```

> Array ( [fname] => [email] => [password] => [repassword] => [username]
>   => )

**Details**

*PHP version(of my PC)* : 7.0.9

*PHP version(of 000webhost)* : 5.2.*

Comment: Can you also add the code from `core/Security.php` line 432 here?

Comment: done adding codes..

Comment: Named capture groups (ie. `(?<name>..)` are recognized from php 5.2.2, prior versions used `(?P<name>...)`

Comment: @Toto any solution because it's a file from `codeigniter` `system` folder and i don't think i should edit this..

Comment: Upgrading the server ;( Really I don't think it is possible to make it works without any changes.

Comment: so I cannot host my website in 000webhost...

Comment: but still my second problem is not taken care of...

Comment: Submit your problem to 000webhost, may be (but not certain) they could do something

Comment: Honestly I'd stay away from any host still running php 5.2. That version is long dead and is not getting security updates.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of CI. Do yourself a favor and get CI 3.1.0